# jBehave doesn't work?

Tags: java, jbehave

I am trying to implement a simple program to learn how to use the jBehave!!.The program is adding two numbers.
I installed the plugin for eclipse from here 
    http://jbehave.org/eclipse-integration.html
then i downloaded the jBehave files from here
    http://jbehave.org/download.html
i added the .zip file to the build path . but i can't import the `org.jbehave.core.*`
any suggestions !?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the zip file for download is the kind of zip file (i.e. jar-equivalent) that can be added to an eclipse build path.

I'd follow the instructions for eother ant or maven:

http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/dependencies.html